# Excel Formulas not Calculating?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

[image]

This is what I'm working with. Until today it counted everything just fine. Suddenly none of the CountIfS formulas are working. I have NO idea why. Help?

All the CountIfS formulas are returning 0, despite the criteria being met.

I've tried messing with the upper case, rewriting the formulas, everything I can think of. Is it something simple I'm missing???

Comment: The string `"TRUE"` is not the same as the boolean value `TRUE`.  Try removing the quotes around that

Comment: @chrisneilsen said ^^^^ `TRUE` --> TRUE